# ImportError: cannot import 'rendering' from 'gym.envs.classic_control'

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm working with RL agents, and was trying to replicate the finding of the this [paper](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/2656), wherein they make a custom parkour environment based on Gym open AI, however when trying to render this environment I run into.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import gym
import TeachMyAgent.environments

env = gym.make('parametric-continuous-parkour-v0', agent_body_type='fish', movable_creepers=True)
env.set_environment(input_vector=np.zeros(3), water_level = 0.1)
env.reset()

while True:
    _, _, d, _ = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    env.render(mode='human')
    time.sleep(0.1)

c:\users\manu dwivedi\teachmyagent\TeachMyAgent\environments\envs\parametric_continuous_parkour.py in render(self, mode, draw_lidars)
    462 
    463     def render(self, mode='human', draw_lidars=True):
--> 464         from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering
    465         if self.viewer is None:
    466             self.viewer = rendering.Viewer(RENDERING_VIEWER_W, RENDERING_VIEWER_H)

ImportError: cannot import name 'rendering' from 'gym.envs.classic_control' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\teachagent\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\classic_control\__init__.py)

  [1]: https://github.com/flowersteam/TeachMyAgent
```

I thought this might be a problem with this custom environments and how the authors decided to render it, however, when I try just

```
from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering
```

I run into the same error, github users [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/2656) suggested this can be solved by adding `rendor_mode='human'` when calling `gym.make()` rendering, but this seems to only goes for their specific case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got (with help from a fellow student) it to work by downgrading the `gym` package to 0.21.0.
Performed the command `pip install gym==0.21.0` for this.

**Update, from Github issue**:

Based on https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/2779

This should be a problem of gymgrid, there is an open PR: [wsgdrfz/gymgrid#1](https://github.com/wsgdrfz/gymgrid/pull/1)
If you want to use the last version of gym, you can try using the branch of that PR (https://github.com/CedricHermansBIT/gymgrid2); you can install it with `pip install gymgrid2`

Comment: I was under the presumption that I answered that this solved the problem! The paper doesn't list dependencies with gymgrid, thanks for the help!